# type 'PieSeriesRendererExtension' is not a subtype of type 'CartesianSeriesRenderer'

Tags: flutter

```
series: <CircularSeries>[
              PieSeries<GDPData, String>(
                dataSource: _chartData,
                xValueMapper: (GDPData data, _) => data.name,
                yValueMapper: (GDPData data, _) => data.gdp,
                dataLabelSettings: DataLabelSettings(isVisible: true),
                explode: true,
                explodeIndex: 1,
              )
            ],
```

'type 'PieSeriesRendererExtension' is not a subtype of type 'CartesianSeriesRenderer''

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing **SfCartesianChart** widget with **SfCircularChart**

Comment: worked, thank you!

Comment: Pleased to help you..:)